# asyncjs: `Uncaught (in promise) Error:..`

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async.js

I am using the times() method of async.js (https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times).

It basically calls an async function X amount of times, and then once every async function resolves, it gives you the opportunity to consolidate your results in one callback.

I notice when I mimic a 404 or any error, I can pass the error to the final callback and either render a visual prompt to the user, log it to the server, etc.

Whenever I force an error, I always get an error in my console also:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected status code [404] on URL...`

Am I doing something wrong in terms of handling this error (Should I actually not being seeing this if I was handling the error correctly)?

My async function, and then my `times()` implementation basically looks like:

```
var getPrismicStories = function(pageNumber, callback) {
  let stories = [];

  Prismic.api("https://myendpoint.prismic.io/api",{accessToken}).then((api) => {
        return api.query(Prismic.Predicates.any('document.type', ['blog-posts','video-posts']),{pageSize : 100, page : pageNumber, orderings : '[document.first_publication_date desc]',after:lastInitialStoryId})
  }).then((prismicResponse) => {
    stories = prismicResponse.results;
    callback(null, stories);
  }).catch((error) => {callback(error,stories)});
};

times(4, (i,next) => {
  getPrismicStories(++i, function(err, stories) {
    next(err, stories);
  });
}, function(err, allStories) {
  if(err){
    console.error(err);
  }

  doSomethingWithFetchResults(allStories);
});
```

I am forcing the 404 for instance, by requesting an incorrect URL name (`"notmyendpoint.prismic.io/api"`).

Comment: @Xufox it has been posted.

Comment: Do not use async.js with promises.

Comment: You will want to [use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, Why shouldn't I use promises, and what is the difference in the comparison in your comment?

Comment: @Bergi Also, do these recommendations pertain to my original problem in any way?

Comment: I said you should not use async.js, not that you should not use promises :-) The difference between the two snippets is explained in detail in the linked answer. And yes, if `callback` throws (which is quite likely given that you call `doSomethingWithFetchResults` even when there was an error), this might be the reason for your problem.

Comment: @Bergi Why should I not use async.js :O

Comment: Because promises are superior to callbacks, and mixing them doesn't work well (as you experienced). `times` is really trivial to write yourself with promises if you want.